# Does the target of the Delectable Flesh spell get a save?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, saving-throw, targeting

I'm playing an evil game and found a wonderful spell, but I am unsure if the target would get a save because they're not the ones affected by it.

[Delectable Flesh](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/delectable-flesh/) has target of "all creatures in a 15-foot-radius burst centered on a single living creature". It allows both will negates and spell resistance.

Does the central target get to save against it, or can their SR even negate the whole spell? My thought is that only those who would be affected are allowed the save and SR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Only Targets get to make a Save and are allowed Spell Resistance.

If we look at the [Targeting rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Aiming_a_Spell) for spells we see:

> Some spells have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself.

Then we look at [Saving Throws](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Saving-Throws):

> Usually a harmful spell allows a **target** to make a saving throw to avoid some or all of the effect. The saving throw entry in a spell description defines which type of saving throw the spell allows and describes how saving throws against the spell work.

And finally [Spell Resistance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Spell-Resistance):

> If your spell is being resisted by a creature with spell resistance, you must make a caster level check (1d20 + caster level) at least equal to the creature’s spell resistance for the spell *to affect that creature*.
>
> ...
>
> The spell resistance entry and the descriptive text of a spell description tell you whether spell resistance protects creatures from the spell. In many cases, **spell resistance applies only when a resistant creature is targeted by the spell**, not when a resistant creature encounters a spell that is already in place.

If we look at the target line of [Delectable Flesh](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/delectable-flesh/) we see:

> all creatures in a 15-foot-radius burst centered on a single living creature

The creature the burst is centered on, is within 15ft of itself and thus would be subject to the saving throw and spell resistance. However if we look at the spell's description we see:

> Choose a creature within range as the object of hunger. **All other creatures within 15 feet of the target** that can see or smell the target’s delectable flesh must succeed at a Will save ...

This shows that the creature the burst is centered upon is not actually targeted by the spell, and is thus unaffected. Therefore, they do not get to make a save or have spell resistance apply.

---

Note: As @TheDarkWanderer points out in their [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/151360/47188), the [Special Ability Rules](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=When%20Spell%20Resistance%20Applies&Category=Spell%20Resistance) for Spell Resistance state:

> Targeted Spells: Spell resistance applies if the spell is targeted at the creature. Some individually targeted spells can be directed at several creatures simultaneously. In such cases, a creature’s spell resistance applies only to the portion of the spell actually targeted at that creature. **If several different resistant creatures are subjected to such a spell, each checks its spell resistance separately.**
>
> Area Spells: Spell resistance applies if the resistant creature is within the spell’s area. **It protects the resistant creature without affecting the spell itself.**

Thus, if multiple creatures are affected and one's Spell Resistance protects it, it doesn't stop the spell from affecting the other creatures.